# Apache camel (which EIP to use here?) aggregate/enrich all rows with repeating header data

Tags: java, apache-camel, eip

I have a CSV I am processing formatted like so:

```
01,H2,H3
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
01,H2,H3
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
01,H2,H3
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
02,B2,B3,B4,B5
```

01 specifies header row and 02 specifies a body row.

I need to take the header data and add it to the body messages so I end up sending messages like this:

```
H2,H3,B2,B3,B4,B5
H2,H3,B2,B3,B4,B5
H2,H3,B2,B3,B4,B5
```

I have tried to aggregate but that does not appear to be the right EIP in this scenario, as I am just combining the same message over and over again instead of multiple messages into one... At a fundamental level I need access to the header data in order to process the body (in truth it's just one field). I just don't know how to set a variable as headers and properties are cleared on each exchange. Any tips? Thanks in advance. Let me know if it would help to see the camel route as it stands.

Here is the camel route which may help:

```
  from("direct:inventory")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
    .throttle(100)
    .choice()
      .when(property("CamelSplitComplete").isEqualTo(true))
        .log("Processed ${property.CamelSplitSize} updates")
      .end()
    .unmarshal(csv)
          .log("${body}")
          .aggregate(header("CamelFileLastModified"), new InventoryAggregationStrategy())
          .completionPredicate(header("aggregationComplete").isEqualTo(true))
          .to("freemarker://templates/inventory.ftl")
          .unmarshal().string("UTF-8")
          .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
          .convertBodyTo(JsonObject.class)
          .to("endpoint");
```

[Here is the spec for the data](http://media.wix.com/ugd/4cddbf_b5921dba42bf4157a4d73a60988b1659.xls?dn=%22EASI_846_INVENTORY_STATUS_v1.1.xls%22)

Comment: Honestly I did not get the explanation. I guess seeing the route will help to understand your problem

Comment: I agree with Sergey's comment not exactly sure what you mean but I suspect you are looking at a transformation/translator type EIP. The aggregate pattern does not seem to be the right choice. Maybe show use some examples not just the concept.

Comment: Let me know if seeing the route and data spec sheet help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just go with the simple approach and use a bean.

```
public class CamelHeadersAndRows {
    public static class HeaderBean {
        String header = null;
        public void setHeader(String body) {
            header = body.substring("01,".length());
        }
        public String useHeader(String body) {
            return header + "," + body.substring("02,".length());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final HeaderBean headerBean = new HeaderBean();

        Main camelMain = new Main();
        camelMain.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer:foo?period=1s&repeatCount=1")
                        .setBody(constant(
                                "01,H2,H3\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "01,H2,H3\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "01,H2,H3\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5\n" +
                                "02,B2,B3,B4,B5"
                        ))
                        .to("direct:inventory");

                from("direct:inventory")
                        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
                        .choice()
                            .when().simple("${body} regex '^01.*'")
                                .bean(headerBean, "setHeader")
                                .stop()
                            .otherwise()
                                .bean(headerBean, "useHeader")
                        .end()
                        .log("message: ${body}")
                ;
            }
        });
        camelMain.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks perfect. The issue now is that the regex is not matching 01? Thinking it may be related to needing to cache the stream? I'm not sure. There is no white space visible in the line I'm trying to match.

Comment: Hi, there could well be some other characters in your string or a problem with the encoding. What happens when you print it out (`.log(${body})`)? Or can you set a debug point in the bean and inspect the value?

Comment: I ended up just using some logic in the bean to inspect and take the appropriate action when it detects a header or body row. I was able to consolidate the "bean" into just one function which I believe is not technically a bean any more now, but it works! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it! No worries :)